# shell scripting- getting values from another shell script

Tags: shell

I am using two shell scripts.(Shell script1,Shell script2)
Shell script1 is containing two variables:

```
$one ="cat"
$two="bat"
```

now when I run Shell script2, I need to get these values from Shell script1 and perform some operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `source` shell builtin:

```
# in script2
source script1
```

Comment: I have used the above command and i am getting " line 2: source: s.sh: file not found" exception

Comment: where are the two scripts located?